# Python 2.7 connection to Oracle: loosing (Polish) characters

Tags: python, oracle, python-2.7, character-encoding, polish

I connect from Python 2.7 to Oracle data base.
When I use:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT column1 FROM table").fetchall()]
```

I have got almost proper values for column1 because all Polish characters ("ęóąśłżćń") are converted to ascii one ("eoaslzcn"). Using another tool like SQLDeveloper and using the same select statement I get proper value.

Comment: where are the chars being lost? oracle->python? or python->output environment?

Comment: The chars are lost in Oracle -> Python - below is the solution for that :)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the environment variable `NLS_LANG` to your database language string, something like

```
os.environ['NLS_LANG'] = 'POLISH_POLAND.EE8MSWIN1250'
```

Answer (score 0):

@Mark Harrison - thank you very much ! It works! There is an exact instruction what I did:

I checked in Oracle what is the language:

```
SELECT USERENV ('language') FROM DUAL
```

The response was:

```
POLISH_POLAND.UTF8
```

Then I changed NLS_LA value in Python:

```
os.environ['NLS_LANG'] = 'POLISH_POLAND.UTF8'
```

Using

```
print "%s, %s" % (name, surname)
```

and "> file.txt" in command line I obtained a (proper) file in utf8.